# Faster Pandas groupby on two columns with high cardinality

Tags: python, pandas, performance, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a portion of code that does a `groupby` over two columns, the two of which contain thousands of unique values. The dataset is made of several million rows.

```py
gp = df.groupby(['col1', 'col2']).size()
```

The resulting `gp` is approx. 5-6 million rows, one for each combination of values of `col1` and `col2`.

This works perfectly fine, however it is very slow (several minutes). Is there any way to achieve the same result faster?

Note that I can't resort to simply spread the computation over multiple cores, as all cores are already busy (similar `groupby` operations happen in parallel over all cores, for the remaining columns).

Comment: What are the `col1` and `col2` dtypes? If they are strings or complex types, consider making them integers.

Comment: they are indeed mostly strings, yes — actually I haven't tried using `category` dtype, now you make me think of it I'm gonna try

Comment: Try using `pd.factorize` or similar methods to map strings to integers, and group on the ints. Convert back to str only when you need it. Might save some time. But yeah, other than that, it really depends on the data etc.

Comment: @rafaelc fyi using `categories` data type makes it significantly worse. Converting to integer speeds it by a factor of about 5x though, so great suggestion!

Comment: @rafaelc I made a new (related) question that is a bit broader because I found that most of the time is actually spent elsewhere, in the operations I'm performing — feel free to have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72495322/faster-alternative-to-groupby-unstack-then-fillna

Comment: using `.groupby(..., sort=False)` is a generic tip for speeding up groupby. Another is to ask if it helps to set one or more of the columns as the index beforehand.