# Faster alternative to groupby, unstack then fillna

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fillna

I'm currently doing the following operations based on a dataframe (A) made of two columns with multiple thousands of unique values each.

```py
>>> pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': ['foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'foo', 'baz', 'bar', 'baz'],
    'col2': ['abc', 'def', 'abc', 'abc', 'def', 'abc', 'ghi']
})

  col1 col2
0  foo  abc
1  bar  def
2  bar  abc
3  foo  abc
4  baz  def
5  bar  abc
6  baz  ghi
```

The operations performed on this dataframe are:

```py
res = df.groupby(['col1', 'col2']).size().unstack().fillna(0)
```

The output is a table (B) with unique values of `col1` in rows and unique values of `col2` in columns, and each cell is the count of rows, from the original dataframe, matching this combination of unique values.

```
>>> res
col2  abc  def  ghi
col1               
bar   2.0  1.0  0.0
baz   0.0  1.0  1.0
foo   2.0  0.0  0.0
```

The amount of time spent in each operation is approximately the following:

- `groupby().size()` -> 5%
- `unstack()` -> 15%
- `fillna(0)` -> 80%

The whole sequence can take about 30 minutes on a real dataset (similar structure as above, just more rows and more unique values).

Is there a better/faster alternative to get from (A) the original dataframe to (B) the end-result table? The most costly operation is by far the final `fillna(0)` so I'd be interested in an alternative for this bit in particular, but an entirely different approach would be great as well.

*Note: converting the strings to integer in the original `df` speeds up the `groupby().size()` operation by about 5x, however it doesn't really affect the following operations*

Comment: Do you need to keep this multi index lvl for columns names?

Comment: What happens if you set `fill_value=0` in the `unstack` step? i.e. `df.groupby(['col1', 'col2']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)`

Comment: `pd.crosstab(df.col1, df.col2)`

Comment: @d.b I'm assuming `crosstab` will be slower than groupby + size here.

Comment: @rafaelc it happens that the `unstack(fill_value=0)` doesn't take any longer than before but the posterior `fillna(0)` disappeared completely — massive improvement

Comment: @Drakax I do yes, the intent is to use the resulting `res` as shown above for further motives

Comment: Does it help to use a smaller dtype after `.size()`? Maybe something like `.size().astype('uint16')` (if values fit that type, of course)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take advantage of filling the NAs in the same step as you `unstack` by setting a [`fill_value`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html#pandas.DataFrame.unstack):

```
 >>> df.groupby(['col1', 'col2']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

`timeit` on Google Colab:

```
%timeit df.groupby(['col1', 'col2']).size().unstack().fillna(0)
1000 loops, best of 5: 1.54 ms per loop

%timeit df.groupby(['col1', 'col2']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
1000 loops, best of 5: 1.47 ms per loop

%timeit df.groupby(['col1','col2'])['col2'].count().unstack(fill_value=0)
1000 loops, best of 5: 1.43 ms per loop

%timeit pd.crosstab(index=df.col1, columns=df.col2)
100 loops, best of 5: 8.11 ms per loop
```

**update:** I've included the rafaelc answer

Comment: why using `count()` instead of `size()` in the second example?